# How can I align two bokeh lines with different periods for the datapoints into one figure

Tags: python, bokeh

So I have two datasets:

```
a = [0,1,2,5,4,3,1]
b = [9,2,1,3,6,8,5]
```

Dataset `a` has a period of 416 femtoseconds, dataset `b` has a period of 25 nanoseconds. This is because my application samples a electronic signal with two oscilloscopes and creates two waveforms, `a` and `b`.

I want to plot these signals in one bokeh figure. Just taking the arrays and plotting them creates a misaligned view of the information.

```
p = figure(plot_width=500, plot_height=200)
xrange = range(len(a))
p.line(xrange, a, line_color="blue")
p.line(xrange, b, line_color="red")
```

[image]

How can I align these signals such that they are correctly aligned in regards to time? One of the problems is that the `datetime` object doesn't have enough precision to work with femtosecond time, otherwise I would've converted my xaxis ticker to a datetime one.

Answer (score 0):

You could do a kind of normalization and multiply all your times by `10^9`. Then your nanoseconds can be treated as seconds and your femtoseconds are miliseconds.

Anyway, whatever name you give it, doesn't really matter. Your graph runs from 0 to 25 and you 'femtoseconds data' runs from 0.000001 to 0.000416. I doubt it's going to be readable...

Answer (score 0):

With bokeh it is possible to pass different data from different sources to a `figure`. This can be a `ColumnDataSource` or a `DataFrame` from pandas. Using multiple sources for the different `line`s gives you the opportunity to draw the lines with different periods to the same xaxis.

To make the ticks on the axis more readable, it is good practice to set a formatter. In the example below I used a `CustomJSTickFormatter`.

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
from bokeh.models import CustomJSTickFormatter
from bokeh.plotting import figure, show, output_notebook
output_notebook()

a = pd.DataFrame({'a':[0,1,2,5,4,3,1]}, index=np.arange(0,7*450,450)*10**-15)
b = pd.DataFrame({'b':[9,2,1,3,6,8,5]}, index=np.arange(0,7*25,25)*10**-9)

p = figure(width=500, height=250)
p.line(x='index', y='a', source=a, line_color="blue")
p.line(x='index', y='b', source=b, line_color="red")

p.below[0].formatter = CustomJSTickFormatter(code = '''return `${(tick * 10**9).toFixed(0)}ns`;''')
show(p)
```

[image: Output]

### Comment

Because of the huge difference of `10^6` the blue line looks like a spike. There is harldy to see anything, even if you zoom in for a while.

Of course you could multiple both indexes of the DataFrames with `10^9` first. This way you could avoid the math in the `CustomJSTickFormatter` but the result should be the same.